# Relative line strengths for Balmer-Beta fine structure transitions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, spectroscopy

**In short:**
I am trying to reproduce the relative line strengths for the hydrogen Balmer-β fine structure transitions as given in the following diagram [Wieman1977PhD]:

[image: Fine structure of the Balmer-β line of hydrogen with relative oscillator strengths for the transitions]

Is there any method to calculate the relative line strengths without calculating any transtion matrix elements?

---

**What I tried:**

The familiar sum rule for relative line strengths in $LS$-coupling reads [Herzberg, p. 161]:

> The sum of the intensities of all the lines of a multiplet which belong to
> the same initial or final state is proportional to the statistical weight
> $2J+1$ of the initial or final state, respectively.

Following a comment in the same section...

> The sum rule is not sufficient for an unambiguous determination of the intensities of compound triplets or higher multiplets. In such cases we must use the general theoretical intensity formulae
> derived by Sommerfeld, Honl, and de Kronig [Condon+Shortley], which naturally contain the sum rule.

...I tried to use the equations in [Condon+Shortley, p.238], e.g. for transitions $(\gamma,S,L,J\longrightarrow\gamma',S,L-1,J')$

[image]

...and similar equations for $L'=L$ and $L'=L+1$. (The sum over $J'$ for each set of equations gives the 'sum rule' cited above with the $(2J+1)$-proportionality.)

Applying these equations to the the Balmer-β transitions, I end up with line strengths $S_i$:

\begin{align}
(2\mathrm{P}_{3/2}\leftrightarrow 4\mathrm{S}_{1/2})& & S_0 &= 4\ |(2\mathrm{P}|\hat{P}|4\mathrm{S})|^2 \\
(2\mathrm{P}_{3/2}\leftrightarrow 4\mathrm{D}_{3/2})& & S_1 &= 4\ |(2\mathrm{P}|\hat{P}|4\mathrm{D})|^2 \\
(2\mathrm{P}_{3/2}\leftrightarrow 4\mathrm{D}_{5/2})& & S_2 &= 36\ |(2\mathrm{P}|\hat{P}|4\mathrm{D})|^2 \\
(2\mathrm{S}_{1/2}\leftrightarrow 4\mathrm{P}_{1/2})& & S_3 &= 2\ |(2\mathrm{S}|\hat{P}|4\mathrm{P})|^2 \\
(2\mathrm{P}_{1/2}\leftrightarrow 4\mathrm{S}_{1/2})& & S_4 &= 2\ |(2\mathrm{P}|\hat{P}|4\mathrm{S})|^2 \\
(2\mathrm{S}_{1/2}\leftrightarrow 4\mathrm{P}_{3/2})& & S_5 &= 4\ |(2\mathrm{S}|\hat{P}|4\mathrm{P})|^2 \\
(2\mathrm{P}_{1/2}\leftrightarrow 4\mathrm{D}_{3/2})& & S_6 &= 20\ |(2\mathrm{P}|\hat{P}|4\mathrm{D})|^2 \\
\end{align}

Which gives a system of linear equations:
\begin{align}
\frac{S_0}{S_4}=\frac{4}{2}&& \frac{S_1}{S_2}=\frac{4}{36}\\
\frac{S_2}{S_6}=\frac{36}{20}&& \frac{S_3}{S_5}=\frac{2}{4}
\end{align}

Thes relative oscillator strengths given in the diagram satisfy these equations, but the other way around they can only be reduced up to a point where three oscillator strengths (e.g. $S_0$, $S_3$ and $S_0$) are free. In other words: To get the relative line strengths across all transitions, I still have to calculate another ratio of two line strengths (at least).

---

[Wieman1977PhD] https://searchworks.stanford.edu/view/975911
[Condon+Shortley] Condon, E.U.; Shortley , G.H. (1959). *The Theory of Atomic Spectra*
[Herzberg] Herzberg, G. (1944). *Atomic Spectra and Atomic Structure*